# HAProxy TCP mode client IP

Tags: haproxy

I use haproxy to forward multiple domains from 1 IP. This works nicely. However I need the client IP to be forwarded to the endpoint, so i added send-proxy to the backend. Now the site stopped loading. When i remove send-proxy it is working again but i need the client IP. Below my haproxy.cfg

```
frontend https_in
    mode tcp
    #mode http
    option tcplog
    #option forwardfor
    bind *:443
    acl tls req.ssl_hello_type 1
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if tls

    acl host_work_domain_com req.ssl_sni -i work.domain.com

    use_backend https_work_domain_com if host_work_domain_com

backend https_work_domain_com
    mode tcp
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server server1 10.11.70.81:443 send-proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

The `send-proxy` option requires that the server understand and implement the *PROXY* protocol, e.g. as documented by http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt

Does your server implement *PROXY*?